# Getting numerical input list from user in python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple calculator that calculates basic statistic functions. I am almost done but I cannot figure out how to make a user input a list of numerical values. This is where I am currently at:

```
#inputList code?
inputList = []
numbers = input('Input your numbers: ').split(',')
for entry in numbers:
    inputList.append(entry)
```

This gives me the error: TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
Here is a link to all the code: http://pastebin.com/B7u5a6LA

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's really just `inputList = input(...).split(',')`, the code you have provided works fine for me. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *actually recreates the issue*.

Comment: Aside: in your linked code you forgot a bunch of `return` statements.  Unlike some languages, Python doesn't automatically return the result of the last line executed in a function.

Comment: @DSM yes yes, now it works! I have forgotten to do that. Silly me. Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: @avi thank you, I used the     inputList.append(int(entry))     and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @aruisdante thank you, for editing my text and providing the solution. ^-^

Comment: @AmrOkasha please accept my answer if it helped you. Click on tick mark which is at upper left of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change those to `int` with `int(some_string)`:

```
for entry in numbers:
    inputList.append(int(entry))
```

EDIT: As suggested by @tobias_k and @DSM, you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) fucntions:

```
inputlist = list(map(int, numbers))
```

Comment: Or shorter: `inputlist = map(int, numbers)`

Comment: added to the answer. Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: Careful: the question is tagged `3.x`, and `map` doesn't return a list in 3.  You'd need `list(map(int, numbers))`.

Comment: oops, great catch. edited the answer. My mind still hung upon python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how robust to bad input you want to be, you can do the following in one line to get it done:

```
inputList = [float(num.strip()) for num in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split(',')]
```

Note that the user entering something that wasn't a number, or something that wasn't a comma delimited list of numbers, will cause this to throw a `ValueError`. If that is something you're worried about.